# SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE DATE_PART(...) is Slow in PostgreSQL/TimescaleDB

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, count, query-optimization

To find the number of rows in a table `temperatures` that exist for every hour, I'm running a series of SQL queries on my PostgreSQL 11.2 database with TimescaleDB 1.6.0 extension. `temperatures` is a TimescaleDB hypertable.

For example,

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temperatures
    WHERE DATE_PART('year', "timestamp") = 2020
    AND DATE_PART('month', "timestamp") = 2
    AND DATE_PART('day', "timestamp") = 2
    AND DATE_PART('hour', "timestamp") = 0
    AND DATE_PART('minute', "timestamp") = 0
```

**Question:** However, this query appears to be very slow (I think), taking about 6-8 seconds per query with no other queries running on this database. The table `temperatures` contains 11.5 million rows. There are about 100-2000 rows for each hour.

Looking for suggestions on improving the speed of such queries. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't apply date functions on the timestamp column: this requires repeated computation for each row (5 total), and prevents the database from taking advantage of an existing index on the timestamp column:

This should be faster:

```
select count(*)
from temperatures
where 
    timestamp >= '2020-02-02 00:00:00'::timestamp 
    and timestamp < '2020-02-01 00:01:00'::timestamp
```

This query uses the half-open interval strategy to check the timestamp column against two constant values.

Comment: Does typecasting the date time string using `::timestamp` make it more efficient?

Comment: Why is there `'2020-03-01 00:01:00'` as the upper boundary? Why the extra minute? Shouldn't it be `'2020-03-01 00:00:00'`?

Comment: @stickybit: actually I think the upper boundary should be `'2020-02-01 00:01:00'` (OP wants everything in the same minute as `'2020-02-02 00:00'`.

Comment: @Nyxynyx: `::timestamp` just makes it explicit that we want to do timestamp comparison.